# google sheet vlookup matter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

can someone please help me to solve this problem?
so as you can see in the image theres an **item name column** that i want to be auto filled with the product name (APPLE, ORANGE, GRAPES, PEAR) when a quantity number is input in one of those item name purchase qty amount data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOJ8S.png)

so i've been trying to use vlookup before, but it only work at 1 column, not the whole data (range for APPLE, ORANGE, GRAPES, PEAR. index for ALL PURCHASE QTY DATA.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s7dm.png)

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this in `Cell_A5`:*

```js
=+filter(F$4:I$4,F5:I5)
```

Comment: thank you so much...... i've been trying the whole day for this, thank you so much Sir.
Can you please enlighten me what is this FILTER used for?

edit: sorry i cant vote your answer since its a new account.